# powershell sort-object and keeps window open

Tags: powershell

I have following script to check the installed software on local and remote machines.
Usually it works fine but i have two problems. It only works when i open it in ISE. If i open it in a normal powershell, the script close immediately. Even a pause or read-host command won't work.
For example here is my script for a local machine. Hope you guys can help me.

```
Function Get-InstalledSoftware {
Param(
    [Alias('Computer','ComputerName','HostName')]
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline=$True,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
        Position=1
    )]
    [string]$Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
)
Begin{
    $lmKeys = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall","SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    $lmReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine
    $cuKeys = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    $cuReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser
}
Process{
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Name -count 1 -quiet)) {
        Write-Error -Message "Unable to contact $Name. Please verify its network connectivity and try again." -Category ObjectNotFound -TargetObject $Computer
        Break
    }
    $masterKeys = @()
    $remoteCURegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($cuReg,$computer)
    $remoteLMRegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($lmReg,$computer)
    foreach ($key in $lmKeys) {
        $regKey = $remoteLMRegKey.OpenSubkey($key)
        foreach ($subName in $regKey.GetSubkeyNames()) {
            foreach($sub in $regKey.OpenSubkey($subName)) {
                $masterKeys += (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    "ComputerName" = $Name
                    "Name" = $sub.getvalue("displayname")
                    "SystemComponent" = $sub.getvalue("systemcomponent")
                    "ParentKeyName" = $sub.getvalue("parentkeyname")
                    "Version" = $sub.getvalue("DisplayVersion")
                    "UninstallCommand" = $sub.getvalue("UninstallString")
                    "InstallDate" = $sub.getvalue("InstallDate")
                    "RegPath" = $sub.ToString()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($key in $cuKeys) {
        $regKey = $remoteCURegKey.OpenSubkey($key)
        if ($regKey -ne $null) {
            foreach ($subName in $regKey.getsubkeynames()) {
                foreach ($sub in $regKey.opensubkey($subName)) {
                    $masterKeys += (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                        "ComputerName" = $Name
                        "Name" = $sub.getvalue("displayname")
                        "SystemComponent" = $sub.getvalue("systemcomponent")
                        "ParentKeyName" = $sub.getvalue("parentkeyname")
                        "Version" = $sub.getvalue("DisplayVersion")
                        "UninstallCommand" = $sub.getvalue("UninstallString")
                        "InstallDate" = $sub.getvalue("InstallDate")
                        "RegPath" = $sub.ToString()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $woFilter = {$null -ne $_.name -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $null -eq $_.ParentKeyName}
    $props = 'Name','Version','ComputerName','Installdate','UninstallCommand','RegPath'
    $masterKeys = ($masterKeys | Where-Object $woFilter | Select-Object $props | Sort-Object Name)
    $masterKeys
}
End{}
} 
  Get-InstalledSoftware | select-object name | sort-object
```

Comment: Do you start the script directly from explorer or from an all ready open PowerShell window? (You should at least try the latter one to determine what is going on.)

Comment: saved my script as .ps1 file and started it direct from explorer

Comment: Are you running it as admin?

Comment: Try `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` at the bottom of the script :D

Answer (score 0):

Send your output *somewhere*, not just to the host window. I suspect the windows closes or your pause command is kicking in before its retrieved the results thus they aren't sent to the host window.

The following works fine for me run as a script:

```
Get-InstalledSoftware | Select-Object name | Sort-Object | Out-Gridview
```

Comment: really don't understand it. it is still the same problem. in ISE no problem, if i start it normally, it pops up and close immediately

Comment: Do you allow unsigned scripts? If not then it wont run as a script.

What do you get if you run Get-ExecutionPolicy -List